# ActiveRecord Select first 10 items for every date for 30 days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

The model is Posts, and each post has upvotes:integer.
Hundreds of posts are created each day, and I want to return the top 10 upvoted posts from each day for the past 30 days with a single query. (300 results)

ordered chronologically

I want to return the results for the past 30days, and show the top 10 posts from each day in the same query.

the expected result should be:

top 10 posts from today, top 10 posts from yesterday ... top 10 posts from 30 days ago.

is there any way to do this query without doing a loop and individual query for each day?

Answer (score 0):

1. Raw SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT (array_agg('id => ' || id || ', ' || 'body => ' ||  body || ', ' || 'upvotes => ' || upvotes order by upvotes desc))[1:10] AS posts, date FROM posts GROUP BY date;
```

it returns hash with 2 values, first is has key posts with array of posts and second value is date

```
sql = "select (array_agg('id => ' || id || ', ' || 'body => ' ||  body || ', ' || 'upvotes => ' || upvotes order by upvotes desc))[1:
10] as posts, date from posts group by date;"

records = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
records[0] = {"posts"=> "{\"id => 8, body => atis atis animatis, upvotes => 9\",\"id => 11, body => Fuga enim sit aliquam., upvotes => 8\",\"id => 20, body => Vel vero fugiat explicabo., upvotes => 8\",\"id => 18, body => Nesciunt dolor voluptatibus ad., upvotes => 7\",\"id => 17, body => Laboriosam qui nam esse., upvotes => 6\",\"id => 13, body => Earum est temporibus odio., upvotes => 6\",\"id => 16, body => Autem qui nam omnis., upvotes => 4\",\"id => 7, body => Facilis aut non aut., upvotes => 4\",\"id => 15, body => Voluptatem non asperiores vero., upvotes => 4\",\"id => 12, body => Nihil facere aut natus., upvotes => 3\"}",
 "date"=>2019-11-24 14:41:34 UTC}
```

Then you can parse result. Hope it helps